# typescript instantiation type definition

Tags: typescript

The function `mynew` receives the class array and returns the instantiated array. How can I define `unknown` to make the error disappear

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function mynew(klass: Type<unknown>[]): unknown[] {
  return klass.map((e) => new e());
}

class ClassA { x = 1 }
class ClassB { y = 1 }

const [a, b] = mynew([ClassA, ClassB]);


// The attribute "x" does not exist on the type "unknown"
a.x

// The attribute "y" does not exist on the type "unknown"
b.y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a solution which does not require to manualy type each generic for each class.

First of all, you can simplify this code:

```js
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

to:

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T
```

In order to reduce repetitive code, you can use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).

In order to infer each class constructor, you can use them in this way:

```js
function mynew<T extends Constructor<any>, Classes extends T[]>(...klasses: [...Classes]) {
    return klasses.map((e) => new e());
}

const result = mynew(ClassA, ClassB)
```

Please hover your mouse on `mynew(ClassA, ClassB)`, you will se that second generic argument `Classes` is infered to `[typeof ClassA, typeof ClassB]`.

Now, we need to iterate through each element in tuple and obtain `[InstanceType][2]`

Here is how we can do it:

```js
type MapPredicate<T> = T extends Constructor<any> ? InstanceType<T> : never

type Mapped<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

// [ClassA, ClassB] 
type Result = Mapped<[typeof ClassA, typeof ClassB]>
```

Please, keep in mind, there is a big difference between `typeof ClassA` type and `ClassA`. First refers to constructor, second to class instance.

Let's put it all together:

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

class ClassA { x = 1 }
class ClassB { y = 1 }
class ClassC { z = 1 }
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type MapPredicate<T> = T extends Constructor<any> ? InstanceType<T> : never

type Mapped<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? Mapped<[...Tail], [...Result, MapPredicate<Head>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

// [ClassA, ClassB] 
type Result = Mapped<[typeof ClassA, typeof ClassB]>    

function mynew<T extends Constructor<any>, Classes extends T[]>(...klasses: [...Classes]): Mapped<Classes> & unknown[]
function mynew<T extends Constructor<any>, Classes extends T[]>(...klasses: [...Classes]) {
    return klasses.map((e) => new e());
}

const result = mynew(ClassA, ClassB, ClassC)
const [a, b, c] = result;
a.x // ok
b.y // ok
c.z // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQCwAKCmYANkyRJY8xQEEoAbygAPMlACMUAL4yVSmGYBCmqCD2GTkuQvNmYNgF73jUgPS%20oTFQIABMAS2AlVjgIJRwoAAtgYDBOfxQmTABrOAA3CFQAM1k4KnpMOABbXyZfAFYABgBmAHY6gCYADgA2KVBIKABVBDDEAjgASQRgAqQIbFGEPEGSclpBqAhtGYQQpR47AH46LK5BkVISXLgwkKguSnzUES2dvbopAEhTqDCEQoKUAmUguVxuIS%20x2Bkk%20DwgTwA3FI%20uBoABZJhgAAKwXCmCYM0IqygBE22wgu3MiBQGGwuDwBxIUOQwB4mAgBFRRPuFHhBWRkn66MxkBCeC%20qlQqDJbyUktQTBAeHQCCyCFKCCIABovgAlWLoWTAGUU97yxXK1XqqiavSCL7E%20UmylQe0w45u2FQJ2vU1KPh-AHSgASAkhrsY9H1SENwC1UAx2NxYXxhODRDDMK4PvJLoD-0BwYgTBC8cjgcBBCYYVkmc%20x0TorwfEjVZrAnjLcY0dj8cTONCKYJEDwRZLGaIXy4%20pLiFkSp7RqISOkkn8rosLlU8c3iksAk%20KIGi%20N5EboWbQrghWUW-jV5vu6Q%206Ih9XhRVC0QUEqIEoVEIZ13ngFlaRwfBGR3MxYiApQCEEIgGEYLJoM4CNGCfWJhC4c8xUwpASAAMigFU1Q1N0PwQL8EB-P9qEA30XRAmksHAhleG1W9FBgxj3nggREMjFCXFiLgu3ofDhE0L5gmAdBUBo4TuKQehKkxWhaAgUFeRoCBaCEIQV0cGRqWNYIYyNPRf3-Wgn23LjnyglwYCEEyWVdJh4wAI3jTABD0czYxXJh6F0dc4CyKQvPoOxwsipx6C8OKgA)

More about iteration through tuple type you can find in [my blog](https://catchts.com/tuples#map)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, is there a better solution

```
function mynew<A, B>(klass: [Type<A>, Type<B>]): [A, B];
function mynew<A>(klass: [Type<A>]): [A];
function mynew(klass: Type<any>[]): any {
  return klass.map((e) => new e());
}
```